# when is using uploader system in codeigniter the system say Call to a member function site_url() on array

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is a very simple file uploading with CI but the system says functions `site_url()` or `base_url()` can't be used in original file Helper Codeigniter

```
$this->config = array('upload_path' => dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])."/images/",
      'upload_url'      => base_url()."images/",
      'allowed_types'   => "png|jpg",
      'overwrite'       => TRUE,
      'max_size'        => "10000KB",
      'max_height'      => "7680",
      'max_width'       => "10240",
      'file_name'       => "about"
            );

$this->load->library('upload', $this->config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('logo'))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_upload', 'You logo has been uploaded' );
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_upload', 'Can\'t Upload this file, Please try agine.' );
    }
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function site_url() on array

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Comment: Don't use `$this->config` because it is already a loaded CI class. Instead,  rename to `$this->upload_config` or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code it will helps you.

```
$obj = &get_instance();
  $obj->load->library('upload');
  $file_name = "about." . pathinfo($_FILES['logo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //userrandom file name instead of about
  $full_path = FCPATH . 'images/';

  $config['upload_path'] = $full_path;
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
  $config['max_size'] = 2048;
  $config['max_width'] = 2048;
  $config['max_height'] = 2048;
  $config['file_name'] = $file_name;

  $obj->upload->initialize($config);

  if (!$obj->upload->do_upload('logo')) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_upload', $obj->upload->display_errors());
    return $obj->upload->display_errors();
  } else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_upload', 'You logo has been uploaded');
    return $obj->upload->data();
  }
```

- don't use `dirname()` for file path .
  use `FCPATH` it will gile you absolute path from root like "`/var/www/html/project_name`"
- `upload_url` is not a key in codeiginter upload library
- use random file name because if you upload another image it will override or create file new file like `file_name(1).extension`

Comment: +1 thank you for answered  me , my problem was it i called config by obj instance CI and i don't use $obj = &get_instance(); >> thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per your [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084312/when-is-using-uploader-system-in-codeigniter-the-system-say-call-to-a-member-fun#comment79130681_46084312) I think you have to load the URL helper first.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or you can load it in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

To Upload the image try this code:

```
$config['upload_path']          = './images/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'png|jpg';
$config['max_size']             = 10000;
$config['max_width']            = 10240;
$config['max_height']           = 7680;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

Comment: Hi @BllyRt if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.